# IE8 bugs overview

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Is there any useful overview/list with IE8-Javascript Bugs and workarounds? Such as:

```
e.preventDefault() --> e.returnValue = true
```

or

```
node.style.width = 500 --> node.style.width = "500px";
```

or

```
e.stopPropagation() --> e.cancelBubble = true;
```

I've online found something like [this](http://haslayout.net/css/) and [this](http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs). But these are only css bugs and one javascript bug.

I need this to fix bugs in my application.

Comment: These should not be called bug. These are IE built in issues, some are for internal security

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/). I'm sure a good search can get you a list like that. StackOverflow is not google.

Comment: The [es5shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) might help.